# Typescript: Type guards not working as expected when using nested readonly property

Tags: typescript

`Quality` can be good or bad, depending upon the type. Here type guards are working fine

```
enum GoodBad {
    Good = 'Good',
    Bad = 'Bad'
}
interface IQuality {
    readonly type: GoodBad;
}
interface GoodQuality extends IQuality {
    readonly type: GoodBad.Good;
}
interface BadQuality extends IQuality {
    readonly type: GoodBad.Bad;
}
type Quality = GoodQuality | BadQuality;

let quality: Quality;
if (quality.type == GoodBad.Good) {
    let goodQuality: GoodQuality = quality; // No Problem. Working good.
    let badQuality: BadQuality = quality; // Throw error. Working good.
}
```

But now when I wrap quality in `Product` then

```
interface IProduct {
    readonly quality: Quality;
}

interface GoodProduct extends IProduct {
    readonly quality: GoodQuality;
}
interface BadProduct extends IProduct {
    readonly quality: BadQuality;
}

type Product = GoodProduct | BadProduct;
let product: Product;
if (product.quality.type == GoodBad.Good) {
    let goodProduct: GoodProduct = product; // Throw error. Working Bad.
    // let badProduct: BadProduct = product; // Throw error. Working fine.
}
```

Type guard don't work as intended.

1. Whats the difference b/w this `if` block and previous `if` block?
2. `let goodProduct: GoodProduct = product;` why it is throwing error?
3. One solution is to create another `readonly type: GoodBad` on `IProduct`. But this is extra, can this be eliminated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type guard will affect the `quality` field, not the `product` variable. Type-guards only impact the field that owns the discriminating field; it does not affect the owner.

So this works:

```
type Product = GoodProduct | BadProduct;
let product!: Product;
if (product.quality.type == GoodBad.Good) {
    let goodQuality: GoodQuality = product.quality; // Ok
    let badQuality: BadQuality = product.quality; // Err
    let goodProduct: GoodProduct = product; // Err, product not affected
    let badProduct: BadProduct = product; // Err, product not affected
}
```

Your solution of adding an extra field is a good one, another would be to create a custom type guard:

```
function isGoodProduct(p: Product)  : p is GoodProduct {
    return p.quality.type ===  GoodBad.Good
}
if (isGoodProduct(product)) {
    let goodProduct: GoodProduct = product; // OK
    let badProduct: BadProduct = product; // Err
}
```